# Reference a path name in `find` output results

Tags: shell, find, command-substitution

What I would like to do is to be able to reference a `find` path name result as a parameter to another command without laboriously typing the full path name. Example:

```
$ find -name testfile  
path1  
path2  
path3  
$ cd path2
```

How can someone do this?

Comment: You can do something like: `command \`find -name testfile\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, if a variable has the value of a full path to a file (i.e. /home/spider/src/myscript.py) you can use variable manipulation to get the basename and the dirname.

So, for example:

```
filepath='/home/spider/src/myscript.py'

filename=${filepath##*/}
echo $filename
myscript.py

path=${filepath%/*}
echo $path
/home/spider/src
```

Bash builtin read command, support reading from stdin into an array, with the -a option, so you can use this:

```
IFS='$\n' read -d '' -a files < <(find . -name testfile -type f)
```

The shell array variables now contain all files with their path. Using the previous shell string manipulation constructs you can now do

```
cd ${files[2]%/*}
```

To change to the second file's path.

Some notes about the command above:

- option -d '' (be aware of the space between -d and '') select the null character as delimiter for read.
- option -a, as seen above, read the standard input into an indexed array (named 'files' in this case)
- < <(command) redirect the output of the command between <( and ) to the standard input. That's handy for read, to which you cannot pipe.
- I've added '-type f' to the find command, to be sure you get only files
- For reference [string manipulation operands in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)
- You can use basename(1) and dirname(1) command, for the same purpose, but they spawn a new process, so are a little less efficient.

Comment: Thanks spider. Where can I read up on how to manipulate variables like you did here> ${filepath##*/}?

Comment: What is this doing?> IFS='$\n' read -d '' -a

Comment: You can find good doc here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html (it's linked in the answer as well)

Comment: It changes the Internal Field Separator to newline to split the output of find (which are lines) into words, then -d '' uses the Null character as a delimiter. Nice side effect is that it works also for files/path  with space in the name. more info here http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS

Answer (score -1):

Can you run the other command as a part of the `find` statement?

```
find -name testfile -exec othercommand {} \;
```

`{}` is the path that was found.  The arguments to `-exec` have to be terminated with a semicolon, `;`, but you need to escape that in bash with a backslash, `\`.

This example would change permissions on every found file:

```
find -name testfile -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: Welcome to nix.SE! You might want to consider expanding your answer with links to documentation or relevant resources that would further help the OP.

Comment: But, this method acts on all the paths. I just want to pick a individual path. I can't cd to multiple directories at the same time

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question what you were trying to do, so it was hard to give a useful answer.